# DataTable.js - automatic init

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am trying to automatically init all data tables:

```
var dataTables = document.getElements('table.datatable');
for(var i= 0; < dataTables.length; i++) {
  dataTables[i].DataTable();
}
```

My table:

```
<table cellspacing="0" class="table datatable table-striped table-bordered no-footer" id="articlestable">
```

But I get the following error:

> TypeError: dataTables[i].dataTable is not a function

Anyone knows what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try with JQuery?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('table.datatable').dataTable();       
 });
```

Comment: @w0rldart I believe it does. OP is selecting a DOM element using getElementById, then expecting it to have jQuery functions attached to it, of which dataTable() is an extension. **This answer selects those elements and runs the method, which will exist, on each.**